# Trying to transpose row data into their own columns in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I'm trying to transpose row data in a dataframe to be a unique column for each value. I have a vertical top-down report, and need to break it out into a horizontal-style report. I'm using alpaca API that makes a dataframe, but now a new version creates a different dataframe structure. Columns have been eliminated and I need them back. Other code that relies on the old style dataframes will be hard to re-tool.

The original dataframe was horizontal, with unique column, with four sub-columns in the header for each stock ticker.

[image: Horizontal dataframe]

But now it's producing a vertical dataframe. The unique columns are now under 1 column **symbol** as row values.

[image: Vertical dataframe]

This is how I build the dataframe using api features.

```
df_ticker = api.get_bars(        
    tickers,
    timeframe,
    start=start_date,
    end=end_date,
    limit=1000
).df   # to make it a dataframe.
```

I tried to transpose the values of the **symbol** column using the **pivot_table()** function to make the stock values their own columns again like original dataframe, but it didn't come out good.

```
df_ticker_fixed = df_ticker.reset_index()
df_ticker_fixed = df_ticker_fixed.pivot_table(
    index='timestamp',
    columns='symbol',
    values=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    ) 
df_ticker_fixed.head()
```

[Result has incorrect column headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lKWS.png)

What I basically need is make that double-header column format again, where there's a column  with sub-divided columns underneath. I don't know what that's called when you have two layers of columns in a report.

Answer (score 1):

This is called a MultiIndex and you want to [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) after your `pivot`, with an optional [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df_ticker_fixed = (df_ticker
 .reset_index()
 .pivot_table(
    index='timestamp',
    columns='symbol',
    values=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
    )
 .swaplevel(axis=1)
 .sort_index(level='symbol', axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
)
```

Comment: This is great! This saves me from having to re-code stuff.